# append byte arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, arrays

I have 2 arrays of bytes, and i want to copy/append them in the byte array _allBytes.

How can i do that? Any suggestions are welcome.

```
Byte _secretBytes[6];
Byte _saltBytes[4];


// append the two arrays
Byte *_allBytes[(sizeof(_secretBytes) + sizeof(_saltBytes))];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Byte _allBytes[(sizeof(_secretBytes) + sizeof(_saltBytes))];
memcpy(_allBytes, _secretBytes, sizeof(_secretBytes));
memcpy(_allBytes + sizeof(_secretBytes), _saltBytes, sizeof(_saltBytes));
```

Or, using the Foundation framework (since your question is tagged with iOS/Objective-C):

```
NSMutableData *allData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[allData appendBytes:_secretBytes length:sizeof(_secretBytes)];
[allData appendBytes:_saltBytes length:sizeof(_saltBytes)];
Byte *allBytes = [allData mutableBytes];
// Or: 
// const Byte *allBytes = [allData bytes];
```

Comment: thanks, this works, i added in the title that it was for xcode but somebody removed it, so i'm using the foundation framework

Comment: @jonasvermeulen: You are welcome. - (Xcode was removed from the title because Xcode is the IDE, not the language or framework.)